I cant get black extension to format on save or work period with python
Black formatter for python on visual studio code doesnt work for me.
I tried changing the default json file to the black extension and that didnt work and I do have a folder where my python file is in.  Down below I have included my json file. Please if anyone could help I would appreciate it.
"[html]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[css]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 150,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": true,
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.pytestParameters": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter"
    },
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "vsicons.presets.foldersAllDefaultIcon": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "intelephense.format.braces": "k&r",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": null,



I believe the solution can be found in the settings screen in VS Code as it might be possible that the file you are formatting is in another workspace.

Go to settings in VS Code (ctrl + ,)
Search for 'Default Formatter'
Select Black Formatter
Search for and enable 'Format On Save'

Be sure to apply these changes across VS Code for convenience.
Black can also be used through the terminal in case you are still running into issues.
# For Windows
Black example\\path\\main.py
# For Linux
Black example/path/main.py


I have tried adding it as the default and that doesnt work unfortunately. Now in the terminal how do I add it on Mac?

I have not used MacOS but I believe it follows the same syntax as Linux. Easiest way to get the file path is by right clicking the file in VS Code explorer side panel and click the "copy relative path" option.
Then, in the VS Code terminal, type "Black main.py", with main.py being your file path. You should see a confirmation message in the terminal that the file was reformatted.
